# How to include a condition in an If Elif Else in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to input into a dataframe if someone is highrisk due to certain variables such as BMI and if they smoke. I figured how to do it separately between the two variables but I need them to be together so, when the BMI is greater than 30 and less than 19.99 and smokes it says high risk while right now it either says the condition for just smokes or just BMI.

this is my dataframe rn

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({     
    'Name': ['Jordan', 'Jess', 'Jake', 'Alice', 'Alan', 'Lauren'],     
    'Age': [26, 23, 19, 20, 24, 28],     
    'Sex': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F'],     
    'BMI': [26, 22, 24, 17, 35, 20],      
    'Smokes': ['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'No']`
})    
display(df)
```

ill do this for BMI

```
def assign_Result(BMI):
     if BMI >= 30 or BMI <= 19.99:
         result = 'high risk '
     elif BMI >=25<=29.99:
        result = 'medium risk '
     else:
        result = 'low risk'

     return result 

df['Result'] = df['BMI'].apply(assign_Result) 
display(df)
```

and ill do this for smokes

```
def assign_Result(Smokes):
     if Smokes == 'Yes':
         result = 'High Risk '
     else:
         result = 'Fail'

     return result 

df['Result'] = df['Smokes'].apply(assign_Result) 
display(df)
```

but when i try to combine it either says error or only complies to one condition wither BMI or Smokes

Comment: When you copy and paste your code, highlight what you pasted and click the `{}` button in the editor. It will add 4 spaces to the front of each line of code and that will preserve white space and line feeds. Currently your question is very difficult to decipher since even your pasted code is multiple lines pasted as one. I have fixed the first code block as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You want the risk to be high if `BMI < 20` or `BMI >= 30` or `Smokes == 'Yes'`. You can check those conditions individually for the *entire `df["BMI"]` and `df["Smokes"]` series*, and then set the values accordingly. Here, we use the `|` operator (which is the bitwise OR operator in python, but Pandas overrides it to mean element-wise OR) for the boolean calculation. Similarly, `~` is the bitwise NOT operation, which is overridden to elementwise NOT by pandas

```
high_risk = (df["BMI"] < 20) | (df["BMI"] >= 30) | (df["Smokes"] == "Yes")
```

This gives `high_risk` as a Series of booleans:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
dtype: bool
```

Similarly, calculate the medium-risk case, and the low-risk case (which is when neither `high_risk` or `med_risk` are `True`)

```
med_risk = (df["BMI"] >= 25) & (df["BMI"] < 30)
low_risk = ~(high_risk | med_risk)
```

Now, you can set the rows where each `*_risk` is `True`:

```
df.loc[high_risk, "Risk"] = "High"
df.loc[med_risk, "Risk"] = "Medium"
df.loc[low_risk, "Risk"] = "Low"
```

This transforms your dataframe to:

```
     Name  Age Sex  BMI Smokes    Risk
0  Jordan   26   M   26     No  Medium
1    Jess   23   F   22     No     Low
2    Jake   19   M   24    Yes    High
3   Alice   20   F   17     No    High
4    Alan   24   M   35    Yes    High
5  Lauren   28   F   20     No     Low
```

This approach is faster than using `apply`, because it operates on the entire column at once instead of processing the dataframe row-by-row.

---

If you *really* want to use `apply`, you can use similar conditions on both the `BMI` and `Smokes` columns. Since each row only has a single `BMI` and `Smokes` value, you can use Python's regular logical `or` and `not` operators:

```
def get_risk(row):
    if row["BMI"] < 20 or row["BMI"] >= 30 or row["Smokes"] == "Yes":
        return "High"
    elif 25 <= row["BMI"] < 30:
        return "Medium"
    else:
        return "Low"
```

Then, `df.apply` with `axis=1` applies this function to each row, and returns a `Series` where each element is the result of the function for that row.

```
df.apply(get_risk, axis=1)
```

```
0    Medium
1       Low
2      High
3      High
4      High
5       Low
dtype: object
```

You can assign this to the `Risk` column of your dataframe to get the same result as before:

```
df["Risk"] = df.apply(get_risk, axis=1)
```